# Relationship between time.time() and file.getmtime()?

Tags: python

I'm writing a test for Path.touch from `dkfileutils`:

```
class Path(str):
    def touch(self, mode=0o666, exist_ok=True):
        """Create this file with the given access mode, if it doesn't exist.
           (based on https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pathlib.py)
        """
        if exist_ok:
            # First try to bump modification time
            # Implementation note: GNU touch uses the UTIME_NOW option of
            # the utimensat() / futimens() functions.
            try:
                os.utime(self, None)
            except OSError:
                # Avoid exception chaining
                pass
            else:
                return
        flags = os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY
        if not exist_ok:
            flags |= os.O_EXCL
        fd = os.open(self, flags, mode)
        os.close(fd)
```

I have tried variations of the following..

```
def test_touch():
    before = time.time()
    with open('a', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('a')
    after = time.time()

    assert before <= after

    a = Path('a')
    a_before_touch = a.getmtime()
    assert before <= a_before_touch <= after

    a.touch()
    after_touch = time.time()
    a_after_touch = a.getmtime()

    assert a_before_touch <= a_after_touch
    assert a_after_touch >= after
    assert a_after_touch <= after_touch
```

but it keeps failing (https://travis-ci.org/datakortet/dkfileutils/builds), run 68:

```
>           assert before <= a_before_touch <= after
E           assert 1489532961.064958 <= 1489532961.064464
```

run 67

```
>           assert a_after_touch > after
E           assert 1489532462.412086 > 1489532462.412933
```

run 66

```
>           assert a_after_touch > after
E           assert 1489532286.6042855 > 1489532286.606766
```

Am I just silly in assuming that time.time() and file.getmtime() are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All filesystems allocate only a limited number of bits to storing file timestamps; in some older filesystems, the resolution was one second or worse.  In general, it's never going to give you the same resolution as reading the clock directly.